# I found it's very hard to understand a hypothesis in an advertising repetition's effects study

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, marketing, academia

In the meta analysis study by [Schmidt & Eisend (2015)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00913367.2015.1018460) which won the Journal of Advertising Best Article Award, I found a hypothesis very hard to understand. I don't know whether I'm wrong or not...

In forming their hypothesis 4, the wrote:

> Singh and Cole (1993) have compared the effectiveness of 15-second and 30-
>   second commercials and found that **longer commercials are superior in influencing consumers’ learning and attitude**. Thus, short-duration advertisements need more repetitions to be effective, **which increases the repetition effect on attitude and recall of short-duration advertisement compared to long-duration advertisement.**
>
> H4: The effect of advertising repetition on (a) attitude and (b) recall is **weaker** for the exposure to a long-duration advertisement than for the exposure to a short-duration advertisement.

What I'm thinking is if it has been found "longer commercials are superior in influencing consumers’ learning and attitude", then say let's repeat the ads once, consumers get 30% learning and attitude for the 30' ad while get 15% for the 15' ad.

Then, let's repeat the ads twice, say consumers get 60% learning and attitude for the 30' ad while get 30% for the 15' ad.

So the repetition effect is 60%-30%=30% for the 30' ad, while the repetition effect is 30%-15%=15% for the 15' ad.

So it seems the repetition effect maybe **stronger** for the 30' ad than the 15' ad.

So I'm really confused how their hypothesis is formed. Whether I'm wrong or there is any other explaination?

Comment: Well, it may be stronger, and it may be weaker, that's why the statement "... is weaker" is a hypothesis!

Comment: @jbowman Thanks. I just wonder why the hypothesis is generated this way not the other way around. Is there anything to follow when generating a hypothesis? Are they both the correct way to write the hypothesis?